# Clojure Spec Not Validating Data Properly

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I am super confused by Clojure Spec. When I run in the repl by entering:

```
(require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as s])
```

And then add:

```
(s/valid? even? 10)
```

I get //true. And when I run:

```
(s/valid? even? 11)
```

//False. Ok so that works. Then when I require spec in my core.clj as:

```
(ns spam-problem.core
    (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
              [clojure.spec.gen.alpha :as gen]))
```

And try a simple validation to get it to throw an error, nothing happens:

```
(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (s/valid? even? 11))
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here and am very confused about how spec is supposed to work. I am running this by using command lein run. Is there another way you're supposed to run it?

Comment: `valid` doesn't throw. It returns a Boolean value, which you're not doing anything with.

Comment: Ok, but also does not work with conform. I should have used that in my example instead.

Comment: Conform also doesn’t throw. You may want to use s/assert instead.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you are feeling because once I got into Spec it caused me the same thoughts. What really helped me to solve the problem in my mind is to considering Spec being not a final library but rather a framework. In my projects, usually I've got a special module with high-level wrappers above basic spec capabilities. I believe, you might do the same: define a function that takes data, spec and raises those error message you desire to have in terms of your business-logic. Here is a small example of my code:

```
(ns project.spec
  (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]))

;; it's better to define that value is a constant
(def invalid :clojure.spec.alpha/invalid)

(defn validate
  "Either returns coerced data or nil in case of error."
  [spec value]
  (let [result (s/conform spec value)]
    (if (= result invalid)
      nil
      result)))

(defn spec-error
  "Returns an error map for data structure that does not fit spec." 
  [spec data]
  (s/explain-data spec data))
```

Now, let's prepare some specs:

```
(defn x-integer? [x]
  (if (integer? x)
    x
    (if (string? x)
      (try
        (Integer/parseInt x)
        (catch Exception e
          invalid))
      invalid)))

(def ->int (s/conformer x-integer?))

(s/def :opt.visits/fromDate ->int)
(s/def :opt.visits/toDate ->int)
(s/def :opt.visits/country string?)
(s/def :opt.visits/toDistance ->int)

(s/def :opt.visits/params
  (s/keys :opt-un [:opt.visits/fromDate
                   :opt.visits/toDate
                   :opt.visits/country
                   :opt.visits/toDistance]))
```

And here are some usage examples:

```
(let [spec :opt.visits/params
      data {:some :map :goes :here}]
  (if-let [cleaned-data (validate spec data)]
    ;; cleaned-data has values coerced from strings to integers,
    ;; quite useful for POST parameters
    (positive-logic cleaned-data)
    ;; error values holds a map that describes an error
    (let [error (spec-error spec data)]
      (error-logic-goes-here error))))
```

What might be improved here is to have a combo-function with both `validate` and `error` functionality. Such a function could return a vector of two values: success flag and either result or error data structure as follows:

```
[true {:foo 42}] ;; good result
[false {:error :map}] ;; bad result
```

The Spec library does not dictate a single way of processing data; that's why it's really good and flexible.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this. I think the issue I'm having though is that all the examples online show using spec in the repl and aside from copying and pasting these tests into the repl after entering the namespace I'm working in, I have no idea how to run these tests if they are written in my editor. I am used to Ruby where you just write the tests in a separate rspec doc, require it, then run. If there is any documentation about how to do that in Clojure, would love to see it.

Answer (score 0):

`valid?` is a predicate that returns true or false. Your program isn’t doing anything with the return value. Try printing it to console or using [`s/assert`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.spec/assert) if you want to throw an exception:

> If (check-asserts?) is false at runtime, always returns x. Defaults to
>   value of 'clojure.spec.check-asserts' system property, or false if not
>   set. You can toggle check-asserts? with (check-asserts bool).

So you may need to set `(s/check-asserts true)` to have `s/assert` throw exceptions:

```
(clojure.spec.alpha/assert even? 3)
=> 3
(clojure.spec.alpha/check-asserts?)
=> false
(clojure.spec.alpha/check-asserts true)
=> true
(clojure.spec.alpha/assert even? 3)
ExceptionInfo Spec assertion failed
val: 3 fails predicate: :clojure.spec.alpha/unknown
clojure.core/ex-info (core.clj:4739)
```

Comment: s/assert won't work either and neither does s/conform.

Comment: @JessieRichardson "wont" or "doesn't"? `conform` doesn't work for the same reason as `valid?`; neither throws. Did you try `assert`? From the docs: "Returns x if x is valid? according to spec, else throws an ex-info with explain-data plus ::failure of :assertion-failed."

Comment: spam-problem.core=> (require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as s])
nil
spam-problem.core=> (s/conform even? 1000)
1000
spam-problem.core=> (s/conform even? 1001)
:clojure.spec.alpha/invalid
spam-problem.core=> (s/assert even? 1000)
1000
spam-problem.core=> (s/assert even? 1001)
1001

Comment: In actual editor, no feedback when running lein run. Just: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Unable to open cgroup memory limit file /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes (No such file or directory)

Comment: I'm not sure you have a spec problem. Try just throwing an exception in your main and nothing else: (throw (ex-info "test" {})). I feel like the way you are launching it is a method that does not print out the error out of programs.